# funtion return [ret] for ret to be 2d

Tags: octave

I found this octave function, that returns a tuple in octave:

```
function [ret] = g(x)
    ret(1, 1) = cos(x)
    ret(1, 2) = sin(x)
end
```

I don't get the brackets why for `[ret]`, as we are returning one variable, can you explain please? Because `ret` is a vector, and why vector inside a vector.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets there don’t form a vector, they collect the output variables. It is part of the function signature.

`function [ret] = …` is exactly the same as `function ret = …`. That is, the brackets are optional when there is a single return variable.

The same is true when there are no return variables, `function [] = name(…)` is the same as `function name(…)`.